# Find the value that occurs most frequently and indicate relative frequency

Tags: r, dplyr, count, pipe, transform

I observe 12 responses of 2 survey participants.

```
data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), response = c(2,2,3,3,6,3,6,7,3,1,4,3,3,3,6,4,2,6,7,3,2,1,5,6))
data
   id response
1   1        2
2   1        2
3   1        3
4   1        3
5   1        6
6   1        3
7   1        6
8   1        7
9   1        3
10  1        1
11  1        4
12  1        3
13  2        3
14  2        3
15  2        6
16  2        4
17  2        2
18  2        6
19  2        7
20  2        3
21  2        2
22  2        1
23  2        5
24  2        6
```

Now I want to add 2 things to the data of each survey participant:
a) The most frequent value of this survey participant
b) the relative frequency of the most frequent value

How can I add these things using dplyr:

```
data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(most_frequent_value = ?,
         relative_frequency_of_most_frequent_value = ?)
```

Comment: What if the two subjects have two different values as their most frequent response?

Comment: Good point, let's assume the solution is clear or let's for this example randomly take one of the two. In my real data, I want to identify straightliners in survey data, so if there are two most frequent values, s/he will probably be no straightliner.

Comment: Hi @Scijens, does mine work, just want to know if I got it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a two step solution. First, create a `data.frame` of frequency/relative frequency. Then join to it. We use `slice(which.max())`, because it will return one row. Using `slice_max` may return multiple rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
# count by id, response, calculate rel frequency
# rename columns to make inner_join easier
freq_table <- dd %>%
  count(id, response) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rel_freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
  select(id, most_frequent_response = response, rel_freq)

# inner join to sliced freq_table (grouping by id is preserved)
dd %>%
  inner_join(freq_table %>% slice(which.max(rel_freq)))

#    id response most_frequent_response  rel_freq
# 1   1        2                      3 0.4166667
# 2   1        2                      3 0.4166667
# 3   1        3                      3 0.4166667
# 4   1        3                      3 0.4166667
# 5   1        6                      3 0.4166667
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you do any transformaiton to go from data to "dd"? Because I am getting an error message saying: Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
 no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: No, I did not do any transformation. I just prefer the `dd` name to `data`, as `data` is an existing function in R.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```r
table(data$id, data$response) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames(c("id", "response", "n")) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_max(n, 1) %>%
  group_by(response) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  mutate(ratio = c(n[1]/sum(n), n[2]/sum(n)))

#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   response [1]
#>   id    response     n ratio
#>   <fct> <fct>    <int> <dbl>
#> 1 1     3            5 0.625
#> 2 2     3            3 0.375
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, that works! I meant to compute the intended frequency of the value compared to all other values of this survey participant and not to the frequency of the most frequent value of the other survey participants, but I think i didn't state that clear enough. However, I have a working solution, which is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
data %>% group_by(id, response) %>% mutate(n = n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>% group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(most_frequent_value = response[n == max(n)][1], 
relative_frequency_of_most_frequent_value = max(n)/n())
# A tibble: 24 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
      id response     n most_frequent_value relative_frequency_of_most_frequent_value
   <dbl>    <dbl> <int>               <dbl>                                     <dbl>
 1     1        2     2                   3                                     0.417
 2     1        2     2                   3                                     0.417
 3     1        3     5                   3                                     0.417
 4     1        3     5                   3                                     0.417
 5     1        6     2                   3                                     0.417
 6     1        3     5                   3                                     0.417
 7     1        6     2                   3                                     0.417
 8     1        7     1                   3                                     0.417
 9     1        3     5                   3                                     0.417
10     1        1     1                   3                                     0.417
11     1        4     1                   3                                     0.417
12     1        3     5                   3                                     0.417
13     2        3     3                   3                                     0.25 
14     2        3     3                   3                                     0.25 
15     2        6     3                   3                                     0.25 
16     2        4     1                   3                                     0.25 
17     2        2     2                   3                                     0.25 
18     2        6     3                   3                                     0.25 
19     2        7     1                   3                                     0.25 
20     2        3     3                   3                                     0.25 
21     2        2     2                   3                                     0.25 
22     2        1     1                   3                                     0.25 
23     2        5     1                   3                                     0.25 
24     2        6     3                   3                                     0.25 
>
```